# Magento 2 custom module multi scope store view

Tags: magento2, module, backend, store-view, scope

I am diving into the world of `Magento 2 development`.

I am writing a very simple custom module to show a slider in my store homepage. Each slide has its own title and an image to show and I made them manageable from the backend section following several tutorials on the internet.

Now, my store is in two `different languages`, so two different store views.

How do I add the possibility to insert different values for the same slider in my backend part?

Anyone can point me to same `tutorial/example`? I could not find any..

Comment: On Admin Side. You also need to Put Drop Down for Store View Selection. Which u can find in any of the Magento 2 Module. Use that code & will work

Comment: Thanks. But should I structure the custom module DB tables?

Comment: Yes  u should make Store Id Value In Database & On basis of Displaying Store Front on Frontend Side Display Banners

Comment: Is there any good sample module to look at? Any native or free third party module?

Comment: http://blog.belvg.com/multistore-in-magento-2-0.html or https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/ or https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-create-multiple-store-views-in-Magento-2

Comment: Thanks, but that is an example about multi store, I need just a multistore view module. Something similar to categories or products edit form.

Comment: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-adding-store-view-selection-to-your-modules-adminhtml/

Comment: Thank you again, but the last link is about Magento 1.9. I am developing in Magento 2

Comment: @gianis6 I am building a similar module  and I need the same form to load different store view data how did you go about that?

Comment: @JulianoVargas , unfortunately I didn't manage to do it. If you find any good resources please post them.